# How to design a List Which Google shows it besideof Searched Site Result

Tags: html, html-lists

I have always design sites and application Menu with UL/OL - LI

and I want Google shows my Main Menu beside my Site . what should I consider ?

Answer (score 1):

Google don't publish their algorithm for deciding if they will show sitelinks or not. They do provide [some information in their help](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334&topic=8523).

Comment: Odd, I was always sure it has something to do with specific metadata. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: It wasn't usefull for me. I knowthat google or any other search engine, has an algorythm to make sitelinks. But I want to do something which these search engines determine my site links. so How To do this ?